# Unable to set year in the Date picker on Android 6 using Xamarin (works on previous versions)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Using Datepicker on Android 6 (Marshmallow) I am not able to select the year,
as it only displays the current year to be selected.
I look into documentation and created a datepicker from scratch. Same issue
exists.

It works on Lollipop running api 21/22 
and i used the exact same sample given on xamarin guide here
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/date_picker/

I am using latest Xamarin.Android, which is 6.0 as of now.
Xamarin Studio 5.10

Both shows only 1 year available for the selection
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ng2xa7gaqgv026/Screenshot%202015-11-11%2012.00.47.png?dl=0

Help please?
Thanks.

Comment: It's been almost a year now and this bug still exist.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug to me... You should report it at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com
Should be fixed in next update.